# An error occurred while installing bson (4.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue. When using public.ecr.aws/lambda/ruby:latest Docker

Tags: ruby, mongodb, docker, libssl, aws-lambda-containers

When trying to bundle install in a docker build I am getting this error:
**An error occurred while installing bson (4.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue.**

I am running a Dockerfile for an aws lambda:

```
FROM public.ecr.aws/lambda/ruby:latest

COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock Rakefile Dockerfile ./
RUN bundle config set --local without 'development test'
ENV GEM_HOME=${LAMBDA_TASK_ROOT}
RUN bundle install

RUN mkdir -p /app
WORKDIR /app

COPY lib/ lib/

CMD ["lib/lambda/handler.api_status"]
```

I have tried to update libssl

```
yum install libssl-dev
```

Still not working.

Comment: Please share the full error message, not just only line. Usually somewhere in the full error message or the stack trace, there is a line telling the reason why it failed.